# How to define what expect will send, based on what is the content of script output?

Tags: automation, expect

I have some script, that upon execution returns something like this:

```
1 - some option
2 - nice option
3 - bad option
4 - other option

What number do you choose?
```

and it is waiting for the feedback. I want expect to parse this text and always respond with a digit assigned to `nice option`. The script might change, so sometimes it might be that `nice option` is a option number 2, sometimes it might be option number 4. How could I do that?

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
expect -c 'spawn script.sh
  set timeout 3600
  expect "What number do you choose?"
  send "2\r"
  expect eof'
```

But if the script will change and `nice option` will not be under number 2, then I will have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I found the solution, using only `expect`:

```
expect -c 'spawn script.sh 
  expect -re {(\d)\ - nice option}
  send "$expect_out(1,string)\r"
  expect eof
```

`expect -re` will match using regular expression ( `\d` means "any digit"). Because `\d` is in capturing group or in other words, in parentheses it is saved in regular expression capturing group number 1 ([regexp tutorial link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)). In expect you can reference up to 9 regex capturing groups, outside of this regex, and they are saved in `$expect_out(1,string)`, `$expect_out(2,string)` etc up to `$expect_out(9,string)` ([Google Books link](https://books.google.pl/books?id=Jk2bAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=The+first+is+stored+in+expect_out(1,string),+the+second+in+expect_out(1,string)&source=bl&ots=KrOzb4vQ3c&sig=ACfU3U3jl_uzWqbsASxJCu_zsbxF8q8S4w&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXs8ODz4HkAhV166YKHdCVD30Q6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20first%20is%20stored%20in%20expect_out(1%2Cstring)%2C%20the%20second%20in%20expect_out(1%2Cstring)&f=false)). So if we use `$expect_out(1,string)` instead of `$expect_out(0,string)` we will send only the digit part that get matched in regexp, instead of whole string that would `$expect_out(0,string)` return.